# How does a trait refer to the implementing class?

Tags: scala

For example, I want to declare a trait to say in effect, "If class `C` implements this trait, it has a method `m` that returns an instance of class `C`".

All the ways I can think of just say that `m` returns an instance having that trait, which is not what I want at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You constrain the "self type" like so:

```
scala> trait Foo[Self] { self:Self => def m:Self }
defined trait Foo

scala> class A extends Foo[A] { def m = new A }
defined class A

scala> class B extends Foo[A] { def m = new B }
<console>:27: error: illegal inheritance;
 self-type B does not conform to Foo[A]'s selftype Foo[A] with A
       class B extends Foo[A] { def m = new B }
                       ^
<console>:27: error: type mismatch;
 found   : B
 required: A
       class B extends Foo[A] { def m = new B }
                                        ^

scala> class B extends Foo[B] { def m = new A }
<console>:27: error: type mismatch;
 found   : A
 required: B
       class B extends Foo[B] { def m = new A }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you must be looking for something like this:

```
trait Foo[T] {
  def m: T
}

class A extends Foo[A] {
  def m = {
    getInstanceOfAFromSomewhere()
  }
}

class B extends Foo[B] {
  def m = {
    getInstanceOfBFromSomewhere()
  }
}
```

Testing:

```
object Test extends App {
  val a: Foo[_] = new A
  println(a.m)

  val b: Foo[_] = new B
  println(b.m)
}
```

Output:

```
A@3d246f44
B@14a1373f
```

Hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: That is, but my question is, what would happen if I typed `class B extends Foo[A]`?  Could I make that a compiler error somehow?

Comment: This should be possible with type evidences I suppose, but I actually don't know how exactly you can achieve this

Comment: For your Google-fu: this is called F-bounded Polymorphism and is a common way to simulate `Mytype`s in languages that don't have them (which is pretty much all of them).